# devtools path length

Tags: r, devtools, itk

I'm trying to install ITKR (https://github.com/stnava/ITKR) libs in my R development environment in Windows 10 but I'm running into the following problem when I run `devtools::install_github( "stnava/ITKR" )`

```
:: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (message):
  ITK source code directory path length is too long (67 > 50).Please move the
  ITK source code directory to a directory with a shorter path.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/tmp/RtmpiiQL5o/devtools37c84d7a5f42/stnava-ITKR-805a390/src/itkb/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log"
```

Now I already changed tempdir to 'c:\tmp' and my working directory as well so I cannot possibly trim it further.
Any clue on what I can do to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`C:/tmp/RtmpiiQL5o/devtools37c84d7a5f42/stnava-ITKR-805a390/src/` is a pretty long path. Unless you can influence "devtools" to not use such a long internal path, you are probably out of luck.

Since you are on Win10, another option would be to disable [MAX_PATH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#maxpath) limit and skip [those checks](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L76-L96) and see if ITK still builds correctly. You would need to supply CMake define `ITK_SKIP_PATH_LENGTH_CHECKS` when invoking CMake, e.g. `cmake -DITK_SKIP_PATH_LENGTH_CHECKS:bool=1`.